What is the value of this indefinite integral from QFT?
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}dxdy$$
Wolfram alpha says the answer is $-\pi$. Symmetry says the answer should be zero. Using polar coordinates I find it also to be zero.
This is from a class of integrals of the form:
$$\int \frac{x^T M x}{(x^2+2ax+b^2)^n} dx^d$$
with the special case that $d=2n-2=0$ and $Tr[M]=0$
Since by counting the powers this should normally diverge but due to $Tr[M]=0$ this sort of cures the divergence.
Is there a known formula for this integral in this special case?

What is QFT ? Is it Physics related?

Unless you specify a regularization scheme, you can rewrite the integration to be any real number you want. This is the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem.

@Mathematics Yes, I found this integral when trying to calculate the magnetic moment of the electron. It's full of these weird integrals.

Regularisation means assigning values to divergent series right? like assigning the value $\frac{-1}{12}$ to the infinite series $1+2+3+\dots$ ?

The symmetry does not work here, because the integral diverges. So, the order of integration is important.
WA give the answer $\pi$ - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%7D%7B%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B1%29%5E2%7Ddxdy
I also got $\pi$, integrating in the proposed order
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}dx\right)dy=\frac\pi2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dy}{(y^2+1)^{\frac32}}=\pi$$

Yes, although converting to polar coordinates and doing the $\theta$ integral first I get zero. So taking the limit as the integral region is a series of spherical regions gives zero. But no doubt if you took a series of ellipsoids it would give a different answer.

Fubin-Tonelli does not apply here since, as @svyatoslav mentioned, the double integral $$\int_{(-\infty,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)} \left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}\right|,d(x,y)$$fails to exist.
